# How to create ValueProvider for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, c#-3.0, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create a Valueprovider in ASP.Net.MVC 2 Beta.
My Value source would be a JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out JsonValueProviderFactory from MVC 2 RC Futures.  [Download the source ZIP](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=37423); the particular file you should look at is **src\MvcFutures\Mvc\JsonValueProviderFactory.cs**.  To hook it up, add it to the static ValueProviderFactories.Factories collection from within Application_Start.

Comment: Levi, 
Unable to find it.. which Change Set has this ?

Comment: It's in the linked ZIP file ("ASP.NET MVC 2 RC Source Code").  The MVC 2 preview release sources have been going up as ZIP files in the Downloads tab, not the Source Code tab.